# Wait for images to load after creating them via an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting images (74 files) with an AJAX request. I am loading them in to an array. Then I change some style calling the function `changeMargins()`. The issue is that the function is called when the images are not yet all loaded and ready.

```
imageArray = new Array();     

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function (data) {
    counter = 0
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
      if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|GIF)$/)) { 
        imageArray[counter]= new imageItem(url + val)
        ++counter;  
      }
    });

    changeMargins(imageArray);
```

How can I wait for completion of the AJAX *and* all load events on the Image elements and then continue processing?

Comment: Put your call to `changeMargins()` *inside* the `success` callback

Comment: process inside success callback, or call a function from success callback, or discover jQuery uses Promise/A-, and use the .then method - the choice is yours

Comment: @Rory, which is the existing question? I didn't find it.

Comment: It's in a yellow box at the top of your question. You may need to refresh to see it

Comment: @Rory, if I put the changeMargins() inside the success callback, are you sure it is executed when ALL the images are loaded?

Comment: No, it's run after the AJAX call completes - as that's what your question asked. If your goal is to run the code after all images have loaded I will re-open your question if you can edit it to make that goal more clear

Comment: Mmmh. I have read again my question and it looks clear to me: " The issue is that the function is called when the images are not yet all loaded and ready."

Comment: I did it for you.

Comment: @Rory, than you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is probably best addressed by "promisifying" the image loading process, ie create a promise that resolves when the images have loaded.

There's a design decision to be made ... whether (a) to swallow load errors or (b) to allow any individual error to cause the whole process to fail.

Assuming (a), you would write something like this :

```
function loadImages() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        // other ajax params?
    }).then(function(data) {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) { // promisify the entire image loading proceess
            var imageArray = [];
            var counter = 0; // tally of images that have either loaded or failed to load
            $(data).find('a').get().map(function(element) {
                // map a elements in data to an array of their hrefs
                return element.href;
            }).filter(function (href) {
                // filter out any non-jpe?g|png|GIF 
                return href.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|GIF)$/);
            }).forEach(function(val) {
                // for each match, create a Image() object, push onto the array, attach onload and onerror handlers, and set the `src` attribute.
                var img = new Image();
                imageArray.push(img);
                img.onload = function loadHandler() {
                    counter += 1;
                    if(counter == images.length) {
                        dfrd.resolve(imageArray);
                    }
                };
                img.onerror = function errorHandler() {
                    console.log(new Error('image ' + url + val + ' failed to load'));
                    // Here, you might choose to splice failed Images out of `imageArray`.
                    counter += 1;
                    if(counter == images.length) {
                        dfrd.resolve(imageArray);
                    }
                };
                img.src = url + val;
            });
        });
    }).then(function(imageArray) {
        changeMargins(imageArray);
        return imageArray;
    });
}
```

Notes:

- More typically, one would choose to promisify at the lowest level (ie each Image() individually) but promises are fairly expensive, therefore with 74 images, it's better to promisify *en masse*.
- By promisifying, and returning a promise from `loadImages()`, its caller is informed of completion of the process - you can chain `loadImages().then(...)` and do stuff when the images have loaded/failed.